# Red dwarf variation in Luminosity

Tags: life, luminosity, red-dwarf

I recently saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LS-VPyLaJFM&feature=youtu.be). The creator of the video says that one of the reasons for non-existence of life on planets around red dwarfs might be that these stars can increase **luminosity roughly by a factor of 2** in a matter of seconds which will boil off water from planets. He also said something about Helium/Hydrogen convection belts which are responsible for this. Can someone please explain this phenomenon?

Comment: http://youtu.be/jfvMtCHv1q4

Comment: This explains the convectional properties

Comment: Your question is more on the mechanism, but I think, with a thick enough atmosphere a heating up by double wouldn't be a deal breaker.   Or, a water world, the surface could evaporate but just a few feet under the surface, the temperature wouldn't change much.   A tidally locked planet with life on the ring, they could probably endure a flare-up.  This site says they last 10 days or so.   http://www.mssl.ucl.ac.uk/www_solar/PUS/PO/explosions.html  I don't think they're ideal but I don't think life is "impossible" either.  Life is good at adapting.   Life could dig underground for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The creator seems to be referring to [flare stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flare_star). Flares may be magnetic in origin, like various manifestations of the Sun's magnetic field. These flares can be quit luminous across the electromagnetic spectrum, including in the x-ray wavelengths.

Some red dwarfs are flare stars, though flare activity may be largely restricted to a small part of a red dwarf's lifetime. However, during this period, life on a planet orbiting close to a red dwarf could be in serious danger.

The reference to convection may be that [red dwarfs are generally fully convective](http://arxiv.org/abs/0901.1659), unlike other stars. Magnetic fields in stars are generated via [the dynamo effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamo_theory); in red dwarfs, full convectivity can play a huge role in generating strong magnetic fields, and thus stellar flares.